# Is it possible (and if so, how) to have a terminal open on x-screen 1, execute a command on that terminal, and have an application open on screen 2?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, xorg

Let's say you have two monitors hooked up to the same machine, running gnome (let's call them 'A' and 'B'). Each has its own, independent x-screen.

Our goal is to type a command into a terminal on Monitor A and have that command open an application on Monitor B.

Is there an easy X-command that lets that happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the first display is :0 and the second is :1 then typing

```
DISPLAY=:1 <command>
```

should be enough to get the command to run on the second window.

This will make all subsequent apps run from the terminal session open in the second window:

```
export DISPLAY=:1
```